# phpBB sessions do not carry from page to page

Tags: session, web, integration, phpbb

I have a website (located in the root directory) with a forum located in ./forum/

I have successfully integrated phpBB's sessions into the index of my website using the following codes:

In my index page before `<html>`:

```
<?php include_once("include/phpbb.php");
// check for logout request
$cp = $_GET['cp'];
// is it a logout? then kill the session!
if ($cp == "logout") {
$user->session_kill();
$user->session_begin();
echo "Successfully Logged Out.";
}
?>
```

phpbb.php:

```
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH :  './forum/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
require($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();
?>
```

Displaying the information - this is in header.php which is included in my index:

```
<?php
// Page login notice
if ($user->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS)
{
?>

<img src="forum/images/avatars/gallery/noavatar.png" style="float:left; width:72px; height:72px;">
<div class="login">
    <form method="POST" action="forum/ucp.php?mode=login">
    <ul><li><span>Username:</span> <input class="loginfield" type="text" name="username" size="20"></li>
        <li><span>Password:</span> <input class="loginfield" type="password" name="password" size="20"></li>
        <li>Remember Me? <input type="checkbox" name="autologin"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="forum/ucp.php?mode=register">Register</a></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Login" name="login"></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="../index2.php">
    </form>
</div>  

<?php
} else { ?>

<img src="forum/images/avatars/gallery/<?php echo $user->data['user_avatar']; ?>" style="float:left; width:72px; height:72px;">
<div class="login">
    Welcome back, <?php echo $user->data['username_clean']; ?><br> 
    You have <?php echo $user->data['user_unread_privmsg']; ?> new messages<br>
    <a href="index2.php?cp=logout">Log Out</a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I can successfully log in on the index using the form I created, but if I then click to another page (i.e. about.php) I am asked to log in again. This happens for every page. This also happens if I click over to the phpbb forum.

Is there any way to make it so I can log in on any page, and not have the session restart when browsing other pages?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the cookie path in your board configuration in the phpBB ACP. phpBB by default tries to create restrictive cookies with the board root specified as the cookie path.

If the cookie path is `/forum/`, sessions won't persist in /.